# Need help converting MySQL to MySQLI in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli, migrate

MySQL extension is now deprecated and I need to convert my WordPress site to MYSQLI. I am a complete beginner at PHP and I am really lost.

I'm trying to use a converter tool (https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool) and follow these instructions https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi , but I can't get the tool to work.

I uploaded it to my SFTP and this is the path
example.com/MySQLConverterTool/GUI/convert_directory.php
but every time I try to convert any directory to MySQLI it says "No matching files found in the specified directory".

The instructions says "point the converter tool to the installation path of WordPress" and since WordPress is installed on my root directory doesn't that mean the installation path is example.com/ ? I have tried example.com/wp-content, example.com/wp-admin etc. and for every directory I try, it says "No matching files found in the specified directory".

Am I pointing to the wrong directory? Should the tool be placed in a different folder?

I am willing to try and manually convert to MySQLI but I have no idea where to start, like I said I have little knowledge of PHP.

Please help!

Comment: To be honest I would use PDO, it's much better. But where are these mysql calls from? wordpress? I should think that an up to date installation would do that for you.

Comment: Ah, this is not about Wordpress. You must have some custom written code that is working -against- Wordpress by **not** using the native Wordpress methods. Otherwise, Wordpress will automtically choose mysqli_ since something like 2.0.5 and we're on 4.2.2 now. You are not going to be able to use an "Auto converter tool" unfortunately, those are widely toted and regarded as being functional, however, they hardly ever work properly.

Comment: That auto-conversion tool is not going to work for WordPress. Even though it uses a tokenizer-approach, it's just suitable for literal mysql_* calls littered over legacy applications. More abstract database APIs like that of medium-recent WP versions aren't. -- And if you don't understand PHP mostly, then no, a manual conversion isn't advisable either. -- Not saying this is a bad question. Just not answerable. (Btw, you are likely already confusing URLs with local file paths.)

Comment: My WordPress is up to date (Version 4.2.2) and I am only wanting to use MySQLI because my whole site broke and when I asked my hosting company what to do (WP Engine), they said I need to convert my code to MySQLI.

Comment: Ok so any suggestions or documentation on what I need to do? This is the error my site is getting "Could not successfully run query (SELECT name, value FROM wp_simple_shortcodes WHERE 1) from wp_simple_shortcodes: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses its own Database abstraction class, [called WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), for use in WordPress and WordPress plugins. You can also find out more about the WordPress [Database API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_API). Further I took a look at the [src/wp-includes/wp-db.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php) file which indicates WordPress will fallback on MYSQLi if needed.

Comment: Ok my WordPress is up to date so it should be automatically choosing MySQLI. But my site will not load and is getting this error "Could not successfully run query (SELECT name, value FROM wp_simple_shortcodes WHERE 1) from wp_simple_shortcodes: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(13)" so what files do I need to update the code? I never wrote any custom php code for this site at all. Could it be from a plugin?

Comment: Did you recently make any changes to WordPress (install/remove plugins, update WP, etc.)?

It looks as if there is an issue with the MySQL db itself or your local configuration file is wrong. Check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Default_wp-config-sample.php for latter and if all checks out there, speak with your hosting provider.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I figured out it was caused from an outdated plugin called "Simple Shortcodes" using a old version of PHP.